# Any free entity-recognition programs that can be run programatically on eclipse?

Tags: entity, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to find an entity recognition program that I can modify such that it will recognize new names of people I add. For example, if I were to add "XYZ" as a name, I would be able to do so and the program will recognize "XYZ" as an entity in text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Stanford CoreNLP by using patterns with either the RegexNER or TokensRegex annotators.  Here's [an example](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner/).

Comment: Can you please give me some sample code on how I can do this? I'm currently downloading the StanfordCoreNLP.

Comment: for example, can you please give me code that would make the ner recognize "XYZ" as a person? I set up a project in eclipse and uploaded all the jar files.

Comment: here's what i have so far:

  // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution 

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
     
String text = "Shelley is a Citigroup employee";
// create an empty Annotation just with the given text
     
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
// run all Annotators on this text
     
pipeline.annotate(document);

Comment: // these are all the sentences in this document
     // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
     List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

Comment: for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
         // traversing the words in the current sentence
         // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
         for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
           String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
           // this is the POS tag of the token
           String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
           // this is the NER label of the token
           String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);   
         }

Comment: System.out.println(word + " " + ne);

Sorry for the lack of read ability.. But I hope you get the idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Also, I have added "regexner" to the StandfordCoreNLP.properties file. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: I figured out that I can add my own names and tags to the type_map_clean under regexner. Is there a way to do this programmatically rather than prying into the jar file? I want to include this in an application.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a link to a (newly created) example.